# Inject ViewModelProvider.Factory to different Activity using dagger

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger-2, dagger

I have the following activity where a user logs in. When ever the request is successful and the API returns a valid `LoggedInUser` I would like to navigate to a different activity and still have access to that `LoggedInUser`.

The following is my loginActivity:

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val vmFactory = MainViewModelFactory()
    lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener { onButtonClick() }
        val label: TextView = findViewById(R.id.counter)


        viewModel =  ViewModelProvider(this, vmFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        println("stack: ${viewModel.hashCode()}")

        viewModel.userLogin.observe(this, Observer{ user ->
            print("Debug: ${user}")
            if(user != null){
                label.text = user.user.name
                redirectToNextActivity()

            }

        })

    }


    fun onButtonClick(){
        var username: EditText = findViewById(R.id.username)
        var password: EditText = findViewById(R.id.password)
        println(username.text.toString())
        println(password.text.toString())
        viewModel.setUser(username.text.toString(), password.text.toString())
    }

    fun redirectToNextActivity(){
        println("Login done!")
        val intent = Intent(this, SampleActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }


}
```

The following are my ViewModel and ViewModelFactory:

`MainViewModel:`

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel(){


    var _request = MutableLiveData<LoginRequest>()

    val userLogin: LiveData<LoggedInUser> = Transformations
        .switchMap(_request){req ->
            MainRepository.authenticatePlease(req.username, req.password)
        }

    fun setUser(username: String, password: String){
        val update = LoginRequest(username, password)
        if(_request.value == update){
            return
        }
        _request.value = update
    }

}
```

Here is my Factory:

```
class MainViewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return MainViewModel() as T
    }
}
```

The thing is that when I try to get the factory in the new Activity i get the following error:

`SampleActivity has no zero argument constructor`

Ive then tried to pass in the `vmFactory` in my `loginActivity` as follows:

`val intent = Intent(this, SampleActivity(vmFactory)::class.java)`

and I still get the same error.

`SampleActivity` is as follows:

```
class SampleActivity@Inject constructor(private val factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory) : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

- You shouldn't add parameters to Activity's constructors.

Developers don't have access to Android components' constructors since the Android OS controls the instantiation of Activity, BroadcastReceiver, Service, ContentProvider, and Application classes.

Please check for more info : https://levelup.gitconnected.com/understanding-dependency-injection-in-android-af1bb2b7984e

- If you wish to have access to LoggedInUser in  Sample Activity you can send the object as extra parameter in intent

  ```
  fun redirectToNextActivity(loggedInUser: LoggedInUser) {
  println("Login done!")
  val intent = Intent(this, SampleActivity::class.java)
  intent.putExtra("extra", loggedInUser)
  startActivity(intent)
  }
  ```

  Or you could mark the MainViewModel class as Singleton in order to receive the same instance in both of your activities